# Print 30 Dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

**Goal**:
  print dates 2018-01-09 till 2018-02-08 using `date function` in javascript.

**Issue**: 
  After i=24 the date is adding months in `date22.setDate(date11.getDate() + i);` don't know why.

**Demo:**

```html
<script>
var date11 = new Date('2018-01-09');
var date22 = new Date('2018-01-09');
console.log('date11', date11);
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log('->', i);
  date22.setDate(date11.getDate() + i);
  console.log('date22', date22);
  
  trueDate = date22.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
  console.log(trueDate);
  }
  
 </script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `setDate` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), when the value passed to `setDate` is over the number of day in the month the date is updated with the good month.

So, you should not add a value incremented, but you should increment the day number like this ("one by one"):

```js
var date = new Date('2018-01-09');
console.log('date', date);
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log('->', i);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  console.log('date', date);
  
  trueDate = date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
  console.log(trueDate);
 }
```

Comment: thanks without much editing get it to work in my project.! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add `1000*60*60*24` milliseconds to your date each time :

```js
var date = new Date('2018-01-09');
console.log('date', date);
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log(new Date(+date + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * (i+1)));
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem in my approach?

Comment: @Nihal you're using `setDate()` with a value superior to the number days in the current month.

Comment: it was working fine till i=23. after it goes in feb it was adding month in the calculation.

Comment: @Nihal and `23 + 9 = 32`. Which is more than the number of days in January.

Comment: Because setDate() is misleading and doesn't set the Date as in the whole object, just the day/date-portion of the date. Your code ends up acting recursively the moment it crosses the month barrier. So on Jan 31 you set it to 32, now it's Feb 1, but then you set it to Feb 33 and it gives you Mar 5, you set that to Mar 34 and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

It is adding month because you are setting date11.getDate() + i in date22. Since date11.getDate() is 9 and i is 24 the total becomes 33 which is greater then number of days in that month. that's why it increment the month field.
Your logic should be as follow:

```
var date22 = new Date('2018-01-09');
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log('->', i);
  date22.setDate(date22.getDate() + 1);
  console.log('date22', date22);

  trueDate = date22.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
  console.log(trueDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using string operations to perform `Date` calculations.  String operations puts all responsibility for data consistency on your shoulders (like keeping track of days in the month, Daylight saving, etc.).

I would recommend using the internal millisecond counter in the `Date` objects and iterate over this using the build in `Date` methods as much as possible.

Here is an example for finding all dates between two known dates:

```js
var getDatesBetween = (function() {
  //Milliseconds in a day
  var day = 86400000;
  return function getDatesBetween(fromDate, toDate) {
    //Check for invalid parameters
    if (fromDate === void 0 ? true : fromDate instanceof Date === false ||
      toDate === void 0 ? true : toDate instanceof Date === false) {
      //Log an error
      console.error("Invalid parameters");
      //Return and empty list
      return [];
    }
    //Create local date variables to leave original pristine
    //We always put the smallest Date in "from" for consistency
    var from = new Date((fromDate.getTime() < toDate.getTime() ? fromDate : toDate).getTime());
    var to = new Date((fromDate.getTime() < toDate.getTime() ? toDate : fromDate).getTime());
    //Set all data below day to a standardized level
    from.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0);
    to.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0);
    //Return array
    var returner = [];
    //Offset "from" until it is greater than "to"
    while (from.setTime(from.getTime() + day) && from.getTime() < to.getTime()) {
      //Add this day to the return array
      returner.push(new Date(from.getTime()));
    }
    //Return results
    return returner;
  };
})();
//TEST (with mapping example)
var from = new Date("2018-01-09");
var to = new Date("2018-02-08");
console.log({
  from: from.toDateString(),
  'datesBetween': getDatesBetween(from, to)
    .map(function(date) {
      return date.toDateString();
    }),
  to: to.toDateString()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The day is moving onto the next month. Here is a simpler version of what is happening:

```
var d = new Date('2018-01-31'); // last day in January
d.setDate(32); // set date to: d.getDate() + 1 which equals 32
console.log(d); // 2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z or 1st Feb
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get in one array using following function

```
var date11 = new Date('2018-01-09');
var date22 = new Date('2018-02-08');

 function getDates(d1, d2) {
 var oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
 for (var d = [], ms = d1 * 1, last = d2 * 1; ms < last; ms += 
  oneDay) 
    {
    d.push(new Date(ms).toISOString().substr(0, 10));
    }
     return d;
  }
 getDates( date11, date22 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for each iteration of the loop you are mutating the state of date22 directly. So you are getting a cumulative effect on each subsequent loop and therefore running into the issue of overflowing the number of days in the month (as other posters have pointed out).

```
var date11 = new Date('2018-01-09');
console.log('date11', date11);

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
 console.log('->', i);
 var dateToPrint = new Date(date11.getTime());
 dateToPrint.setDate(dateToPrint.getDate() + i);

 var trueDate = dateToPrint.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
 console.log(trueDate);
}
```

The above solution uses a date variable that gets re-created on each loop. This way there no side-effect created by each loop.